# How to check DBMS_OUTPUT size in my oracle DB

Tags: oracle, dbms-output

Im facing below exception in Oracle DB.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [call SRS_ADMIN.SLI_UTIL.copyData(?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

I want command to know the size of DBMS_OUTPUT.

Comment: Actually I have assigned some error value to "inout_error_msg" variable during run time.PROCEDURE copyData (
   inout_error_msg           IN OUT   VARCHAR2
) ......Exception  v_err := SQLCODE;
      v_msg := SQLERRM;
      inout_error_msg := v_msg || '; errorcode--> ' || v_err;

Answer (score 2):

The ORA-06502 error you're getting is nothing to do with `dbms_output`. You get this when you have a `varchar2` variable and you try to put a value that is too long into it.

For example, putting an 11-character value into a 10-character variable:

```
declare
  var varchar2(10);
begin
  var := 'abcdefghikl';
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

You need to get the full error stack; calling the procedure with the same value from SQL*Plus or SQL Developer would give you more information, and pinpoint the line in the procedure where the error occurs.

If you were putting too much into the `dbms_output` buffer, you'd get a different error:

```
set serveroutput on size 2000
begin
  for i in 1..40 loop
    dbms_output.put('12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890');
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('X');
end;
/

ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 2000 bytes
```

As far as I'm aware there is no way to see the current buffer size; [the `dbms_output` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_output.htm) doesn't show anything, and if it's a package variable then you won't be able to see it without a getter function.

---

If you're getting the exception from this:

```
inout_error_msg := v_msg || '; errorcode--> ' || v_err;
```

... then the variable the caller is passing to the procedure is too small:

```
declare
  msg varchar2(10);
begin
  copyData(msg);
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Increasing the size of the *passed* variable fixes this:

```
declare
  msg varchar2(200);
begin
  copyData(msg);
end;
/

anonymous block completed
```

Obviously you'll have to decide how big to make the variable; it needs to be big enough for any possible response. `SQLERRM` can be [up to 512 characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#CJAJBAJG), so you need to allow for that, plus the error code, plus your fixed text, so... erm... 536, at least? To allow for future changes you should probably make it larger so you don't have to come back and modify the callers.